# CSS Loads Page then does Fade In

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions

my html web page loads in really quickly then does this fade in effect. On the homepage it's fine but every other page loads then fades in again. I just want it to fade in. Any ideas?

```
#main-wrapper {
    animation: transitionIn 0.75s;
}

#features-wrapper {
    animation: transitionIn 0.75s;
}

@keyframes transitionIn {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid this completely, you have to apply `opacity: 0;` to your elements (`#main-wrapper`and `#features-wrapper`)  as the regular setting (i.e. in the CSS rules for these elements).

Then the page will load with `opacity: 0;` on these elements and transition them to `opacity: 1;`.

Otherwise the page loads with the default opacity (= 1) before the transition starts, which is what you experience now. In an ideal situation the transition would start immediately, but often it can take a few moments.

P.S.:  make sure to use `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` to let it stay at `opacity: 1`

Comment: Awesome!! Only problem now is it loads but then goes back to opacity 0, any suggestions?

Comment: fixed it with animation-fill-mode: forwards; ! thank you

Comment: Yes,  I just wanted to write that

Answer (score -1):

```css
#main{
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #333;
    animation-name: transitionIn;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes transitionIn {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<div id="main"><div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).